# Finding the general coordinates to the tangent of a circle using Pythagoras with the center point and radius known

Tags: geometry

Question:

[image]

The information given is that the points of the circle's centre are $C(3a,0)$ and the radius is $\sqrt{3a(a+3)}$

I was only able to define a point $(D)$ on the circle's circumference where $CD$ was perpendicular to $QD$ but I was unable to find the length of $QD$ without defining new terms.

I've sat here looking at my book for some time and haven't got an answer can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $\triangle CDQ$ is right-angled at $D$ because the radius is perpendicular to the tangent. You know $CD=\sqrt{3a(a+3)},CQ=\sqrt{(x-3a)^2+y^2}$ and want to find $DQ$.

Comment: ok yes now I see my mistake thank you for your help